# <br /> is making margin for every space in <p>

Tags: html, css, laravel, margin

This is my blade.php

```css
.p {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  border: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td><img align="middle" width="80" height="80" src="{{ public_path('uploads/logos/') . $logo }}"></td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size: 16px; font-color: #000; ">
          <strong>Asset ID:{{$asset->id}}<br />{{ substr($asset->name, 0, 26)}}<br />{{substr($company->print_name, 0, 12)}}</strong></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And for every space that i have in $asset->name he move whole table to right. This is my pdf. I'm using dompdf package.

[image: When text has enough characters for one row]

[image: When text has more characters]

Comment: How did you know that the `<br />` is making "margin" for every space? What do you mean by every space?

Comment: In Your css use `p { }` instead of `.p { }`, you are using `p` tag not `p` class

Comment: <br> and <br/> rendering the dom differently for each browser. Could be break 2 empty line.

Comment: @MJoraid well I use <br /> for breaking the line, I think that that is moving whole table

Comment: @SuperUser It's still same after chaning from .p to p

Comment: please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem as with your current html and styles, this problem does not happen - my guess is though you have not applied a width to your columns - make you image td 80px and it should work

Comment: I don't have the problem stated in my personal example. I do get 'font-color is not a known css property name'.

Comment: @Pete thanks, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

After I added width to my td margins disappeared.

```
<td width="80">
  <p style="font-size: 16px; font-color: #000; ">
  <strong>Asset ID:{{$asset->id}}<br />{{ substr($asset->name, 0, 26)}}<br /> 
  {{substr($company->print_name, 0, 12)}}</strong></p>
</td>
```